Spring boot application not running in STS Boot Dashboard, but starts correctly with mvn spring-boot:run command
I have the following multi-module Maven project structure:
iaas-cockpit (root project)
│
├── iaas-cockpit-backend (module)
│
└── iaas-cockpit-core-lib (module)

iaas-cockpit-backend is a Spring Boot Application and it has a dependency to iaas-cockpit-core-lib library.
I am using the latest STS version for windows: STS 4.23.1
But when running my Spring Boot Application through the Boot Dashboard I get the below error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.wakabunga.feature.users.service.impl.UserServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.wakabunga.core.mapper.UserMapper' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.wakabunga.core.mapper.UserMapper' in your configuration.

While running the same application by right-click >> run as >> maven build... and specifying the goal spring-boot:run, the application starts correctly with no error.
Why Boot Dashboard is not able to resolve and find the Spring beans located in the dependency project?
Is there some missing configs in my Boot Dashboard?
EDIT:
I finally found why this problem occurs. It is due to missing compiled Mapper implementations in the output folder target/classes.
All the generated sources gets correctly compiled in the target/classes output folder after executing mvn clean install and I can launch my Spring Boot App from Boot Dashboard without problems.
But when doing a Maven >> Update Project... in STS, some of these .class disappears and specifically the Mapstruct Mapper implementations.
It looks like STS automatic build is not recompiling Mapstruct implementations into target/classes directory, and this despite having explicitly enabled STS Preferences > Maven > Annotation Processing > Enable Project Specific Settings > Automatically configure JDT APT.
How can I resolve this issue?
Project details:
iaas-cockpit-core-lib library contains Entities, DTOs and different Spring components to be scanned, like Mapstruct Mappers, Spring Configs, JPA Repositories...
iaas-cockpit-core-lib (project)
│
└── src/main/java (source folder)
    │
    └── com.wakabunga.core.mapper (package)
        └── BaseMapper.java
        └── UserMapper.java
    │
    └── com.wakabunga.core.model (package)
        └── BaseEntity.java
        └── UserEntity.java
    │
    └── com.wakabunga.core.dto (package)
        └── BaseDto.java
        └── UserDto.java
    │
    └── com.wakabunga.core.repository (package)
        └── UserRepository.java

The project iaas-cockpit-backend has the main Spring Boot application class configured to scan all the components under the packages com.wakabunga and com.wakabunga.core:
iaas-cockpit-backend (project)
│
└── src/main/java (source folder)
    │
    └── com.wakabunga (package)
        └── IaasCockpitBackendApplication.java
    └── com.wakabunga.feature.users.service (package)
        └── UserService
    └── com.wakabunga.feature.users.service.impl (package)
        └── UserServiceImpl

package com.wakabunga;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.wakabunga", "com.wakabunga.core" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.wakabunga")
public class IaasCockpitBackendApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SpringApplication.run(IaasCockpitBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}

It was a monolithic project and everything worked fine, but since I split it into two modules I have this issue.
This is the iaas-cockpit parent pom.xml:
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!--<version>3.2.3</version>-->
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.wakabunga</groupId>
    <artifactId>iaas-cockpit</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>iaas-cockpit</name>
    <description>IaaS Cockpit Parent Project</description>
    
    <modules>
        <module>iaas-cockpit-backend</module>
        <module>iaas-cockpit-core-lib</module>
    </modules>


    <properties>
        <jdk.version>20</jdk.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>${jdk.version}</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <m2e.apt.activation>jdt_apt</m2e.apt.activation>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <guava.version>32.1.3-jre</guava.version>
        <compiler.maven-plugin.version>3.12.1</compiler.maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data-jpa-entity-graph.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-generator</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-data-jpa-entity-graph.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>${guava.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${compiler.maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>

This is the iaas-cockpit-backend pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.wakabunga</groupId>
        <artifactId>iaas-cockpit</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <artifactId>iaas-cockpit-backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>iaas-cockpit-backend</name>
    <description>IaaS Cockpit Backend Project</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wakabunga</groupId>
            <artifactId>iaas-cockpit-core-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-generator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.wakabunga.IaasCockpitBackendApplication</mainClass>
                    <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

This is the iaas-cockpit-core-lib pom.xml:
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.wakabunga</groupId>
        <artifactId>iaas-cockpit</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    
    <artifactId>iaas-cockpit-core-lib</artifactId>
    <name>iaas-cockpit-core-lib</name>
    <description>IaaS Cockpit Core Library</description>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cosium.spring.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-generator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>20</source>
                    <target>20</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

This is my BaseMapper interface:
package com.wakabunga.core.mapper;

//imports

public interface BaseMapper<M extends BaseEntity, D extends BaseDto> {
    
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    M toEntity(D dto);
    
    D toDto(M entity);
}

This is my UserMapper interface:
package com.wakabunga.core.mapper;

//imports

@Mapper(componentModel = MappingConstants.ComponentModel.SPRING)
public interface UserMapper extends BaseMapper<UserEntity, UserDto> {}

This the BaseEntity class:
package com.wakabunga.core.model;

// imports

@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected UUID id;
    
    @Version
    private int version = 0;
}

This is the UserEntity class:
package com.wakabunga.core.model;

//imports

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class UserEntity extends BaseEntity {
    
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
}

This is my BaseDto interface which is a polymorphic Type for all application's DTOs.:
package com.wakabunga.core.dto;

public interface BaseDto {}

This is the UserDto record:
package com.wakabunga.core.dto;

//imports

@Builder
@With
public record UserDto(
        String id,
        String firstName,
        String lastName,
        String email
        ) implements BaseDto {}

And this is my UserRepository interface:
package com.wakabunga.core.repository;

//imports

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends EntityGraphJpaRepository<UserEntity, UUID>, EntityGraphJpaSpecificationExecutor<UserEntity> {}

When building the project with mvn clean install the implementation of UserMapper gets correctly generated under:
iaas-cockpit-core-lib (project)
│
└── target/generated-sources/annotations (source folder)
    │
    └── com.wakabunga.core.mapper (package)
        └── UserMapperImpl.java

This is the generated UserMapperImpl, we can see that it is correctly generated with the @Component annotation:
package com.wakabunga.core.mapper;

@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2024-06-13T17:56:36+0100",
    comments = "version: 1.5.5.Final, compiler: Eclipse JDT (IDE) 3.38.0.v20240524-2033, environment: Java 21 (Eclipse Adoptium)"
)
@Component
public class UserMapperImpl implements UserMapper {
    ...
}

In the project iaas-cockpit-backend I have a service UserServiceImpl that injects UserMapper in the constructor:
package com.wakabunga.feature.users.service.impl;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl extends AbstractBaseService<UserEntity> implements UserService {
    
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
}
    

I have searched for similar problems in stackoverflow but did found nothing that can resolve my issue.
I have also tried to resolve this by adding automatically the folder target/generated-sources/annotations to classpath:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-generated-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

But this still didn't work.

Is it possible to pass to Eclipse incremental JDT compiler the argument "-proc:full" to force it to compile annotation processors? Maybe it's a solution?
